# Stand alone test domain controller and internet access

Tags: networking, hyper-v, domain-controller

I've created a virtual machine (the VM is running Windows Server 2012 R2) using Hyper-V on my physical Windows 8.1 box for the purpose of testing Dynamics CRM 2013. This virtual machine is the domain controller (domain name CONTOSO), SQL Server and web server. Right now, it has a network adapter called "CRM Virtual Switch" that is an internal network so it obviously can't see the outside world.

Is there anyway to have this machine use my physical machine's network card so I can connect to the outside world without disturbing any other machines on the real domain and network? It'd be a "nice to have" but don't want to spend a lot of time setting it up and networking is (obviously) not my forte.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to clarify what "...connect to the outside world..." means. You'll also need to clarify "...without disturbing any other machines...", too.

If you mean "access websites" by "...connect to the outside world..." and "...without disturbing any other machines..." as "don't interact with other computers aside from the web servers that the VM is accessing" then I'd suggest running a second VM with a minimal OS installation, configured with two virtual NICs, and an HTTP(S) proxy. This proxy VM would have one NIC connected to the virtual switch with your Windows Server 2012 R2 VM, and a second NIC connected to a virtual switch that is also connected to the physical NIC on your laptop.

This arrangement would give you HTTP(S) access to the Internet from the Windows Server 2012 R2 VM, allow you to use either bridging or NAT for the physical connection of the proxy VM, and would allow you to use whatever IP numbering you wanted between the proxy VM and the Windows Server VM.

I'd probably run a minimalist Linux distribution with Squid Cache to do this, but you could easily use a Windows VM with various proxy applications.